# paintEvent is not called after an update() in mouseMoveEvent

Tags: qt, qt5, qpainter, paintevent, qmouseevent

I am using a QAbstractScrollArea and a custom QWidget derivative widget as "the" widget
(having `sizeHint()` overriden).

The application needs to constantly update the QWidget content during `mouseMove` (kind of
a drag, but not exactly, it is a drawing tool to draw lines between objects, thus the mouse
cursor needs to change and the line needs to be drawn on the fly).

The application works fine, e.g., I can render the content properly, scrollbars visible,
I can manually update the viewport during `scrollContentsBy`, etc.

However, regardless that I manually fire an `update()` (or `repaint()`) call in `mouseMoveEvent`, the `paintEvent` will only be called after the "drag" process is over, e.g., the `mouseReleaseEvent` is fired.

And I'm clueless why this happens. Obviously, if I do the update directly within the
`mouseMoveEvent`, it'll be rejected by QPainter (as I can't instantiate a QPainter within
the `mouseMoveEvent` — Qt drops "*paintEngine should no longer be called*" when trying to do that).

Answer (score 2):

Never mix `update()` with `viewport()->update()`.

Comment: I had the same issue with a custom widget extending QAbstractScrollArea. Everywhere I searched claimed that this->update()/this->repaint() would work. Never realised I need to do it on the viewport(). Thanks